# Set margin for content in a pdf itext7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm working with pdfs, I'm merging them first and then creating a heading and a footer for every page of the merged pdf. I'm using one method to merge and a different one to set the header and footer.

For certain documents the header and footer overlaps with the content. I've tried to set margin for the document but it doesn't change anything.

```
public byte[] HeaderAndFooter(byte[] inputPdf)
{
    var dest = new MemoryStream();
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inputPdf.ToMemoryStream()),
                                         new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
    doc.SetMargins(200,200, 200, 200); /* It doesn't matter the
    numbers I set in here the document remains the same...*/
    numberOfPages = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();

    Paragraph header = new Paragraph("This is a header for every page...")
            .SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA))
            .SetFontSize(10)
            .SetFontColor(Color.BLACK);

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
    {
        var pageSize = pdfDoc.GetPage(i).GetPageSize();
        float LeftMargin = 36;
        float BottomMargin = 24;

        float y = pageSize.GetTop() - 72;
        float center = pageSize.GetWidth() / 2;
        doc.ShowTextAligned(header, LeftMargin, y, i, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, 0);
        doc.ShowTextAligned(footerL, LeftMargin, BottomMargin, i, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, 0);
        doc.ShowTextAligned(footerC, center, BottomMargin, i, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, 0);
    }
    doc.Close();
    return dest.ToArray();
}
```

How could I avoid the header and footer from overlapping with the content?

Comment: iText does not "reflow" an existing document (which is at least very difficult for generic PDFs). If you set margins, they are only respected for new content added via the `Document` instance by iText 7.

Comment: Add to @mkl comment [How to create a document with unequal page sizes?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-create-document-unequal-page-sizes)